# HTML/JavaScript/NetSuite Function Getting Incorrect Results

Tags: javascript, html, netsuite, suitescript

I have inline 'html/javascript' that's getting injected into the browser via a Formula(Text) field on a saved search results column (loop). In other words, this creates a button for each row in the results column that will execute javaScript against that particular line/record (i.e. internalid). **While the button links work correctly(i.e. navigate to the correct record), the JavaScript Alert results are producing the same {internalid} for all button click rows**:

```
'<html>
   <a target="_blank" id="Link" href="https://website.com/rectype=142&id='||{internalid}||'">
     <button  id="Button" type="button" onclick=test();> Check-In 
     </button>
   </a>
   <script> 
      function test() {var x = document.getElementById("Link").href; alert(x);} 
   </script> 
 </html>'
```

**Current Alert Results:**
Row 1 [Check-In] Button Click Alert =  https://website.com/rectype=142&id=157
Row 2 [Check-In] Button Click Alert =  https://website.com/rectype=142&id=157

**Desired Alert Results:**
Row 1 [Check-In] Button Click Alert = https://website.com/rectype=142&id=157
Row 2 [Check-In] Button Click Alert =  https://website.com/rectype=142&id=158
Row 3 [Check-In] Button Click Alert =  https://website.com/rectype=142&id=159

Update: need result of whatever the href resolves to, so it can be passed to the script test function.

Comment: It's hard to tell with the limited code you are showing, but if you have multiple `<a>` elements with the same id (Link, in this case), that will not work. Id's must be unique.

Comment: Seems strange the <href's> are able to get the {internalid} dynamically, and navigate to the correct record, after the wrong JavaScript alert is displayed, of course.

Comment: How many <a> elements are there that have the id of "Link"?

Comment: Actually,  this is the full code. A search executes through the UI and this code gets injected into each row returned in the search; the browser then compiles the code and displays my button.

Comment: That is why you are getting multiple <a> elements with the same id. You must change that. It shows the same alert because your function stops looking when it finds the first element with an id of "Link". Id's must be unique.

Comment: but isn't there a way to pass that link dynamically, after it has been processed?Or get it dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `{internalid}` as part of the `<a>` element's id.

I'm not familiar with this syntax, but I believe it would look like this:

```
<a target="_blank" id="Link'||{internalid}||'" href="https://website.com/rectype=142&id='||{internalid}||'">
```

Then your function might look like this:

```
function test() {var x = document.getElementById("Link'||{internalid}||'").href; alert(x);}
```

This assumes that your function has access to `'||{internalid}||'`. If not, you might be able to pass it to the function.

Comment: No bueno! it's now just getting the last {internalid} in the list, whereas, before it was only getting the first.

Comment: Please show the new code. I think you're on the right track based on your comment. If you're creating the <a> elements within a loop please show that code as well.

Comment: '<html><a target="_blank" id="'||{internalid}||'" href="https://xxxx-sb1.app.website.com/app/common/custom/custrecordentry.nl?rectype=142&id='||{internalid}||'"><button  id = "Button" type="button" onclick=test();> Check-In </button></a><script> function test() {var x = document.getElementById("'||{internalid}||'").href; alert(x);} </script> </html>'

Comment: tried to pass the href to the function, but the same result. We need the result of whatever that url resolves to (post processing).

Comment: still getting the last {internalid} in the loop.

Comment: Try passing {internalid} to the function using `onclick=test('||{internalid}||');` and then in the function use `function test(foo) {var x = document.getElementById("Link"+foo).href; alert(x);}`